# Why doesn't the send buttom work in html

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I have made a formular in html, but is must important device the send buttom doesn't work.

I want to send the data from the formular to my own email.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Contactos</title>

<style>

#container{
top: 0;
left: 0;
width:1280px;
height:1024px;
}
#header{
background-color:#60F;
height:150px;

}

#content{
height:800px;
width:1280px;
float:left;
background-color:#60F;
}
#footer{
background-color:#60F;
height:74px;
clear:both;
text-align:center;
}


</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<h1 align="center">&nbsp;</h1>
<h1 align="center">Contacto</h1>

<p align="center">Si deseas comunicarte con nosotros, por favor llena este formulario:
</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>

  <form action="mailto:charliedem20@gmail.com"
  method="post" enctype="text/plain">


  <p align="center">Nombre: <br>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" size="30"
maxlength="100">
    <br>
  </p>
  <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
  <p align="center">Email <br>
    <input type="text" name="email" size="30"
maxlength="100" value="@">
    <br>
  </p>
  <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
  <p align="center">Tema: <br>
    <select name="utilizacion">
        <option value="1">Comentarios o Sugerencias
        <option value="2">Consultas
        <option value="3">Quejas
        <option value="4">Ideas
      </select>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
  <p align="center">Mensaje: <br>
    <textarea cols="30" rows="7"
name="mensaje"></textarea>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p align="center">Enviarte una Copia? </p>
    <div align="center">
      <input type="checkbox" name="recibir_info">
      <br>
      <br>
      </p>
```

This is the send buttom.

And the rest of the code

```
    <br>
      <br>
      <input type="reset" value="Reset"  />     
    </div>
    </form>

    <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>

    <p align="center">
    <a href="index.html">
      <input type="submit" name="volver" id="volver" value="Volver" onclick="window.location.href='C:\Users\Charlie\Documents\TODO" />
    </a></p>

</div>

<div id="footer">Copyright © Siri.com</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to close the form tag after the submit button but whatever html is there won't work they way you are expecting it to. It is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

[`mailto:` as a form action simply is not well supported](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html).

Use an HTTP(S) form action and send the email from a server side script on your server instead of the user's (possibly non-existent) email client.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a separate php script to send the data to your email. As mentioned by @Quentin before `mailto:` is not well supported.

You could use PHP Mailer to send the data to your email. Here is more information about this https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer